# Import a scheduled functions to another file python

Tags: python, authorization, schedule

I am making a tool to post-registration information to an API, using python. I'm having a problem with the token expiring. The token's expiration time is 300 seconds, so I have to constantly refresh the token. Is there any way I can schedule a token refresh after 300 seconds?

I have a python script in a file called `logAPI.py` containing multiple tasks, processes and functions (and it works).
I have another file called `authorization.py` containing a function that calls to authorization API and returns a token so I can call other APIs.
Since the token expires time is 300 seconds, I intend to return a new token after 300 seconds.

I tried while function, schedule module, cron module and import os but I failed with all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the most straightforward solution you can do without having a separate thread to refresh the token.

`AuthToken` contains the active token as well as the logic needed to refresh it. When you need a token, you call `AuthToken.get()`. This fetches a new token if it's the first time it's being called, or if the token has expired. When the new token is fetched, it's stored in the `_auth_token` singleton. This caches it for later and also lets us know when it's expired.

It sounds like you're using multithreading, so I added a `Lock` to prevent a race condition when calling `AuthToken.get()`

It's important that you always call `AuthToken.get()` before making a request. Even just making two requests back-to-back, there's a possibility the token might expire before the second request is sent.

You may also want to adjust the TTL to be slightly lower in case there's latency making the request.

```py
import requests
import time

from threading import Lock
from typing import Optional
from typing_extensions import Self


class AuthToken:
    """Represents an auth token used by the API."""

    # A singleton AuthToken instance
    _auth_token: Optional[Self] = None
    _lock = Lock()

    # The token's TTL (in seconds)
    ttl = 300

    expires: int
    token: str

    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
        self.expires = time.time() + self.ttl

    def is_expired(self):
        """Returns True if the token is expired."""
        return time.time() >= self.expires

    @classmethod
    def refresh(cls, lock=True):
        if lock:
            cls._lock.acquire()

        # do API request...
        token = "foo"
        cls._auth_token = AuthToken(token)

        if lock:
            cls._lock.release()

    @classmethod
    def get(cls) -> Self:
        """Returns a valid auth token, refreshing the current one if it's expired."""
        cls._lock.acquire()

        if not cls._auth_token or cls._auth_token.is_expired():
            cls.refresh(lock=False)

        cls._lock.release()

        return cls._auth_token


def request_that_needs_token():
    auth = AuthToken.get()

    # use auth.token in your request
    requests.post(
        "http://example.com", headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth.token}"}
    )
```

Comment: Thank @Jessia. My logAPI file will read the records from the tsv files, then reference those records to set parameters and post to the API. I want to find a way to make it so that I don't need to refresh the token every time I send a post request. I want the token to be refreshed only when it has expired, and I will do a re-process to the record that was stopped midway.

Comment: @H.Dang This only refreshes the token if it's expired.

Comment: Thank for your anwser, @Jessie. Can you suggest me if token expires before 300s, how to trigger token refresh process? In addition, the returned data also has a refresh_token with an expiration time of 1600s. Ex: the token was rejected from the server due to a leak

Comment: @H.Dang I updated my answer. You can manually refresh the token by calling `AuthToken.refresh()`